# Android game collision detection

Tags: android, collision-detection, collision

i have a question about android games.I cant make a collision between 2 objects.The rectangle collision seems work perfect in java but in android is not. I am using
the intersect method to check collision.If you guys have some tips or answer to my question please feel free to tell me , i will appreciate all kind of help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: Does the android library that provides the rectangle object work the exact same way as the Java library? It might be better to write your own collision detection algorithm.

Comment: yes it work prefect i just downloaded source code of a simple java game with rectangle collision and if works

Answer (score 1):

Collision detection never has anything to do with the platform and language. The algorithm you use should work properly if it's a good one.

Here's an [article](http://www.gamedev.net/page/resources/_/technical/game-programming/collision-detection-algorithm-r754) to get you started and give you a good hint as to how to proceed about it.

There are certain libraries to help your cause.I recommend you to use the [Box2d](http://www.4feets.com/2009/03/2d-physics-on-android-using-box2d/) library.It is a physics engine with good support for collision. You can find an example on the front page of the site as well.

Comment: thank you i read it but its a bit confusing for me cause i am new to programming :)

Comment: Look at the Box2d page. It is good to get you started. And the GameDev article wasn't so programming related for you to give that excuse. :-)

Comment: Box2d is for physics games,it detects collision 2 but it is not worth to load all that stuff i your game only to make a collision detection :)Thank you for your help , i appreciate that :D.I will try to do the article example and see if its work.

Comment: I just found why the intersects method didnt work.It was just because rectangles didnt move with characters -.- .Now i have an other problem
, i cant change the x and y position of enemy class when it collides.I made methods to access it , but when i try to change it it says "The left-hand side of an assignment must be a variable".What can i do?(if you didnt understand my English , post a comment to rephrase.);

Comment: Ok i found the solution. Thanks you for your time :)